# Why use the first token of a line as the sentence vector

Tags: nlp, doc2vec

In Tomas Mikolov's doc2vec implementation, the first token of the sentence is used as the sentence vector. But I don't know if this will take up the first token and affect its word vector. 
I consider setting a sentence vector separately for each sentence, which is equivalent to a word, just like a word in the context window with an offset of -1 or at the end.And it is also initialized like other words.
I am not sure if this is correct. Maybe I have not understood the method of Tomas Mikolov? Hope to hear from you。

Answer (score 0):

Using the first token on a line as the key for retrieving the learned pargraph-vector is just a quick-and-simple input-format convention. It made it easy for Mikolov to implement the 'Paragraph Vector' algorihm as a small patch to `word2vec.c`, with just a slight special-handling of that 1st token.

When you use the code in that patch, with the paragraph-vectors flag activated, the 1st token is *not* treated like a normal word as part of the the rest of the sentence/contexts.

If you need more flexibility, you could look at implementations of the same algorithm in other libraries. For example, the 'Paragraph Vector' algorithm is available in the Python `gensim` library as the class `Doc2Vec`, and includes many more options - including training more than one doc-vector from a single text, other controllable meta-parameters, and idiomatic Python data sources.